# Using plist or JSON as a UIDocument format in iOS10/Swift3

Tags: ios, json, plist, uidocument

My application has a very basic document similar to a contact card, along with a series of images. I am using UIDocument because I want to have iCloud syncing.

I'm trying to decide how to store the little text information I need, and it would seem that JSON or plists would do fine.

Is anyone out there using either of these formats as the basis for a UIDocument application that might have some advice on which to choose?

Comment: I'd love to hear an update on your decision there, particularly with the new Codable protocol for Swift 4

Comment: No decision made to date, I got pulled off to other tasks. I haven't looked at Codable yet, but I have seen people mentioning it.